# Compile and link libxml2 with Open Watcom for Win32 console application

Tags: dll, libxml2, watcom

We have a Windows 32-bit console application written in C and compiled using Open Watcom. We would like to use the libxml2 library with our application. We found the Win32 DLL binaries, can we link them with our application's code using the Watcom compiler?